# Why doesn't -= operator resize the Form size like += do?

Tags: c#, winforms, height

I can resize automatically my form size at run-time using:

```
Height += X
```

But

```
Height -= X
```

Has no side effect. It doesn't change anything in the form. Why that and how can I force the form to resize?

Comment: Maybe `AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly` ?

Comment: Or there's a MinimumSize property set.

Comment: `Height += 10` works and after than `Height -= 10` doesn't decrease the heigh?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It did worked for me: I changed `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink` Thanks!

Comment: close and downvote? isn't this a programming question or it's too vague or too noob? I'm sorry downvoter.

Comment: @GrantWinney: It did worked in my case...

Comment: @boboes: Was excatly that.

Comment: Height -= 50; works perfectly fine. If your X > 0 then MinimumSize is set..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are running into a minimum possible size issue - many controls allow you to access their size properties but do not allow changes or certain changes to come into effect.
You can experiment with possible values in the designer and see which ones it rejects or alters.

It may be that a property of your form is affecting this - for example the MinimumSize property.